# Only want 2 markers on Google Map. Any previous are deleted

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to have the user click once, lat/lngs are saved to inputs. (this I have). Then they can click again and the next lat/lngs are saved to a second set of inputs. If they click again, the first marker is erased and new marker location is saved. Once user is happy, they click Save and 2 sets of lat lngs are saved in database.

I'm far enough along to catch a click and place in text boxes to save. But not sure how to do the second marker and erase the 1st if I do a 3rd, and so on.

```
//MAP CLICKED
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
    map.panTo(event.latLng);
    var clickposition = event.latLng;
      //MAP CLICKED
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
            marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
            map.panTo(event.latLng);
            var clickposition = event.latLng;
```

To visualize a simple user case:
I open page with embedded google map. I click at a point way up a river. Then I click on a point way down the same river. Lets say I change my mind, I move the points. One at a time, or only one.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I was able to fill all 4 text inputs with 2 different sets of lat/lngs as I click along, except that the previous markers are still on the map. this is how I did it, using a previousMarker global variable. Not sure how to remove previous unused markers.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
    map.panTo(event.latLng);
    var clickposition = event.latLng;


    document.getElementById('lat1').value = clickposition.lat().toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById('lng1').value = clickposition.lng().toFixed(6);

    if (previousMarker) {
        document.getElementById('lat2').value = previousMarker.getPosition().lat();
        document.getElementById('lng2').value = previousMarker.getPosition().lng();

    }

    previousMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(clickposition.lat().toFixed(6), clickposition.lng().toFixed(6))
    });
```

Comment: Where is the code for the markers?

Comment: I put the code for the markers in.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do this is to store all the markers you create in an array. The you can iterate over them, remove them, move them into other arrays, and just overall have more control over them.Something like:

```
var allMarkers = [];
var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(clickposition.lat().toFixed(6), clickposition.lng().toFixed(6))
});
allMarkers.push(newMarker);
var newMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(clickposition.lat().toFixed(6), clickposition.lng().toFixed(6))
});
allMarkers.push(newMarker2);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    allMarkers.forEach(function(element,index,array) {
        // Move
        element.setPosition(event.latLng);
    });
    // Or remove
    allMarkers[0].setMap(null);
});
```

Hope that helps you overall in storing and accessing markers again.

Comment: thanks tempranova! I will accept this for the answer because you treated my question as real. I used your code to load array but I couldn't figure out how to "leap frog" the markers along so I put a "Delete Markers" button above the map in case they had to start over. Acceptable hack until I figure out how to reference the last 2 items in an array and delete the rest. Have a great week!

Answer (score 0):

One option, only have two markers.  Once they have been created, move them to the new location.  Track the number of click (times a marker has been created/moved) and alternate which marker is changed by the click based on whether it is odd or even.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hm8sdbvf/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var marker1;
var marker2;
var previousMarker;
var clickCount = 0;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    if (!marker1 || !marker1.setPosition) {
      marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        title: "#" + clickCount + ":" + event.latLng.toUrlValue(6)
      });
    } else if (!marker2 || !marker2.setPosition) {
      marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        title: "#" + clickCount + ":" + event.latLng.toUrlValue(6)
      });
    } else if ((clickCount % 2) == 0) {
      marker1.setPosition(event.latLng);
      marker1.setTitle("#" + clickCount + ":" + event.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
    } else {
      marker2.setPosition(event.latLng);
      marker2.setTitle("#" + clickCount + ":" + event.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
    }
    if (marker1 && marker1.getPosition) {
      document.getElementById('lat1').value = marker1.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);
      document.getElementById('lng1').value = marker1.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6);
    }
    if (marker2 && marker2.getPosition) {
      document.getElementById('lat2').value = marker2.getPosition().lat();
      document.getElementById('lng2').value = marker2.getPosition().lng();
    }
    clickCount++;
    map.panTo(event.latLng);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="lat1" />
<input id="lng1" />
<input id="lat2" />
<input id="lng2" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: ooooo. I can't wait to get home to try this. I had a similar idea last night of having 2 marker variables and if empty, load marker1. If marker1 filled, load marker2, if both filled, move marker1 variable's content to marker2's content and fill marker1 with new click location. It looks like you are using text inputs to hold marker values which is fine and actually easier for me to understand. Ah, love these puzzles.

Comment: well, used your fiddle code and commented out my click event code. Then on click I stuck call to functions that uses www.GeoNames.com to get nearest place, state, abbreviation, and zip code (can't use Google if you aren't using it on a map. . . I am saving it to a table). I took off the map.panTo(event.latLng); for now at least to cut down on surprises and might try to figure out how to average the 2 markers to center the map in the middle. I heard boundary functions does that pretty easy. Thanks a bunch.